# How to make clustering between two Oracle Database instances

Tags: oracle, database-administration, windows-server

I have two virtual servers and I installed Oracle 19c on only one server, and I need to install another Oracle database on the second server and I need to make clustering in the database between the two servers. How to do this? Is this available using Windows Cluster?

Comment: Which edition - Standard or Enterprise - are you using? Oracle RAC may require additional licensing.

Comment: Will you want to use RAC and have multiple instances open with the same database or are you just wanting normal Windows Cluster failover so you can bring up the instance on another node if one has issues?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not use windows cluster to deploy oracle RAC. You should oracle's own software (Oracle Cluster ware) to do it.

2.To deploy oracle RAC:
a.If you installed database as a single instance,at first you should convert it to RAC and then through oracle addnode procedure, add the second node to cluster.

b.If your installation is a RAC you should do the prerequisite on the second node and using oracle addnode script, add the second node. in recent versions of oracle addnode has a graphical interface also.

Comment: Not only that but most importantly there should be shared storage.